# Flutter: Project won't compile after 'pod update'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

getting error after update pubspec.yaml file
e.g. i am trying to add
**fluttertoast: ^7.1.1**
dependency in pubspec.yaml and **import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';**
in main.dart

when i run this project Error:

```
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                            8.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    lib/main.dart:29:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'visualDensity'.
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart:201:11: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't
    match.
      factory ThemeData({
              ^
    ../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/media_query.dart:126:32: Error: The getter 'physicalDepth' isn't defined for the
    class 'Window'.
     - 'Window' is from 'dart:ui'.
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'physicalDepth'.
            physicalDepth = window.physicalDepth,
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 8.
```

anyone have step by step solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try Flutter pub get?

Comment: yes, also try it

Comment: It seems your implementation is the problem here. From the error message above, your use of VisualDensity is the problem. Try either of the answers below:

Answer (score 0):

It seems ThemeData class had not been loaded correctly in memory. Try this solution:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub cache repair
```

- right-click the ThemeData in your console/error
- go to C: \ BACKUP \ flutter \ packages \ flutter \ lib \ src \ material \ theme_data.dart.
- look up the VisualDensity definition to see if it was there

And if the above doesn't work, try adding the following to your MaterialApp:

```
  ThemeData(
     primarySwatch: appThemeColor,
     visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
   )
```

Comment: but after some time same error  
have you any complete or permanent solution for this?